# How to assign value to model property in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to change the value of somecolumn textbox on change event
that value is changing properly.

but I am not getting value of var1 on Ui.

but I got value of var1 in js fie .

following is the c# code in view

```
     <div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>column name (number: @Model.var1) </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.somecolumn, new { @class = "form-control"})
        </div>
     </div>
```

following is the js code

```
$("#somecolumn").change(function () {

var somecolumn= $("#somecolumn").val();
var var1= $("#var1").val(); //I am getting this value here

var newvalue= parseFloat(somecolumn) + parseFloat(var1);
$("#somecolumn").val(newvalue);
$("#var1").val(var1);

});
```

where I have to change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi `var1` is label ? or inputbox ?

Comment: @Swati I want to show value of var1 in label

Comment: Try like this -> `$(".form-group label").text(var1)`